# In LuaSql, how to use a connection pooling?

Tags: database, postgresql, lua, connection-pooling, pooling

I've been working on **Lua** / **Torch** and I've been using **LuaSql** to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I've reached the maximum number of connections several times, and now I would like to use some sort of **connection pooling** for my database management system.

I've looked for it online but I did not find anything useful. I read [this webpage](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+with+Database) but it seems that the connection pooling ain't available for LuaSql.

Does anybody know if there is any connection pooling system available for LuaSql? If yes, how could I use it?

Comment: May be you do not close connection correctly.

Comment: I wish that was the problem... I checked them all and they all work properly

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of connections in your PostgreSQL or using a tool like Pgpool?

Comment: I did not know about Pgpool. How could I implement it in Lua and Torch? Thanks

Comment: Pgpool is middleware that sits between PostgreSQL server and a PostgreSQL database client - it allows you to reuse connections sharing the same parameters - you can download from here: http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Downloads

Comment: https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer